# Why optopt is 0? C

Tags: c, switch-statement, getopt

I don't understand why optopt is zero in my code when an option is recognized but is right when it goes to the '?'case. This is the code:

```
...
int opt;
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, OPZIONI))!= -1){
        switch(opt){
        case 'h':{
            printOption();
        break;
        }
        case 'f':{
            if(conf->socketname[0] == '\0'){
            strncpy(conf->socketname, optarg, strlen(optarg));  
        }
        else printf("Option %c have to been used one time\n", optopt);
        break;
        }
...
similar code here
...
        case '?':{
        printf("Option %c not recognised\n", optopt);
        break;
        }
```

In else of case f optopt is 0 and it is not printed, but in the case '?' is printed right.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. I can't understand the question. Where is `optopt` defined, and what part of this code is supposed to give it a value? If this is a global variable that should be set by using `getopt`, then please try reading the documentation to understand how it will be set. "Sorry for the not indentation but I don't know how to use stackoverflow" Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and [edit] the post to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`getopt()` only sets the `optopt` variable in the case of an error that makes it return a `'?'` or `':'`. It doesn't set it when it finds an expected option. So using it when `getopt()` returns `'f'` is pointless; it's not going to have any meaningful value in that case.

Comment: And you know which option letter was returned — the value is in the local variable `opt`, so you can print the option name using `opt` instead of `optopt`.